# Voronoi Diagram composed of $n$ randomly distributed points

Tags: probability, geometry, random-variables, variance, voronoi-diagram

I've been curious about the distributions of the areas of cells in Voronoi diagrams. Say $n$ points are drawn from $\text{Unif}([0,1]\times [0,1])$, and a Voronoi diagram is constructed on the unit square. If $A(n)$ is the random variable describing the area of a random cell, what is it's probability distribution function $f_A(x)$? If there isn't a clean expression for the PDF, can we compute $\text{Var}(A(n))$? I know that $E(A(n)) = \frac{1}{n}$ by symmetry, but don't know if we can make a similar argument for the variance. Any thoughts or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would be surprised if this was easy.  Simulation might give you a way forward for particular values of $n$

Comment: @Henry :  [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0406116.pdf) is an answer.

Comment: @JeanMarie - that seems to have involved a lot of simulation and then curve fitting

Comment: @JeanMarie this is great, thanks!

Comment: Do you know that it is the tip of an iceberg: Stochastic geometry. Here are for example good (theoretical!) lecture notes: https://people.cmm.minesparis.psl.eu/users/figliuzzi/Stochastic_Geometry.pdf There are very good books on this domain, for example "Stochastic Geometry and its applications" by Sung Nok Chiu, Dietrich Stoyan, Wilfrid S. Kendall, Joseph Mecke